# How to use gVim to to move from above to below

Tags: vim, edit, move

This is a small part of the file, the original file has hundreds of rows.

I am very sorry because the unofficial English language, instructions are translated by machine out, I hope you can see and understand.

I use a gvim windows platform.Thanks again!

jinan 48 (2) [2013/10/18] indicated mean is:jinan (match place,venue) + space +48 (2) (matches Played  ) + space + [2013/10/18] (match date)

With the match date, matches Played, match place them as a condition to determine the comparative thus achieving the qualifying rows one by one together. Note: The original file is not a regular, so I think it should be used to determine the conditions to find qualified before they can move to the last row.

**Before the modification**

```
jinan 48(2) [2013/10/18]
jinan 48(1) [2013/10/18]
jinan 47(2) [2013/10/18]
qindao 48(2) [2013/10/18]
qindao 48(1) [2013/10/18]
qindao 47(2) [2013/10/18]
jilin 48(2) [2013/10/18]
jilin 48(1) [2013/10/18]
jilin 47(2) [2013/10/18]
yantai 48(2) [2013/10/18]
yantai 48(1) [2013/10/18]
yantai 47(2) [2013/10/18]
……
```

**After the modification**

```
jinan 48(2) [2013/10/18]
qindao 48(2) [2013/10/18]
jilin 48(2) [2013/10/18]
yantai 48(2) [2013/10/18]
jinan 48(1) [2013/10/18]
qindao 48(1) [2013/10/18]
jilin 48(1) [2013/10/18]
yantai 48(1) [2013/10/18]
jinan 47(2) [2013/10/18]
qindao 47(2) [2013/10/18]
jilin 47(2) [2013/10/18]
yantai 47(2) [2013/10/18]
……
```

I want to know how to use gvim to meet certain conditions to achieve the line can move put together.Thanks again!

Comment: You will have to explain what the difference b/w in the input and output are, what change are you attempting to make? Are you attempting to sort lines by their 2nd column?

Comment: The original line does not need to make any changes, just put the same time the same match in a different place names one by one race moves
Qingdao, Jinan, Jining, Yantai is a place name
jinan 48 (2) [2013/10/18] indicated mean
jinan (place name) + space +48 (2) (match Race) + space + [2013/10/18 (Time)

Comment: Try the mentioned answer and see if it works.

Comment: The answer given is not feasible, I use a gvim windows platform.

Comment: @shixin There [is](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/coreutils/) sort for windows. It is feasible.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to sort lines by the 2nd column.

You can use the unix `sort` command to do this:

```
sort -k 2 -r -s  input_file.txt > sorted_output.txt # That's a lot of flags ...
```

- To do this from inside vim, you can select the lines by going into
  `VISUAL LINE` mode.
- Select the lines you want to sort.
- Then press `:`
  to enter an ex mode command.
- Type `!sort -k 2 -r -s %` infront of the
  already present `:'<,'>` so your ex buffer looks like:

.

```
:'<,'>!sort -k 2 -r -s
```

- Hit enter.
  Your lines will be replaced by the sorted input.

If you have a lot of lines and you want to use this on all lines, you can select all lines by doing `VggG` and then running the aforementioned `ex` mode command.

As Zyx pointed out, the `%` is not necessary after the `!sort` command (and incorrect in this case) when using visual mode.

Comment: The answer given is not feasible, I use a gvim windows platform.

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question.

Comment: Sorry,Use your reply tried or not, I added some notes in the original, I hope you can learn more about my needs. Thank you!

Comment: @ffledgling When using `sort` you need either `'<,'>` or `%` in command-line and `:e`. Not both. Try selecting *part* of the text and run your command with and without `%`. *Without* `%` it will sort selected lines as expected. *With* if you are lucky it will replace *the selected text* with the sorted *whole file*. If you are unlucky it will replace selected text with nothing because `%` is not going to work if filename contains special characters (like spaces) which is pretty common on Windows.

Comment: @ZyX Thanks for pointing that out! I'll admit I didn't know the difference before you pointed that out, fixed accordingly.

Comment: Also adding `-n` so that 5(1) stays below 48(2) and so on, apparently sort has no problems even if the characters are not all digits.

Comment: @ffledgling With `-n` `sort` does not give a damn about `(1)`/`(2)` part and according to OP this is essential. Previous variant was better.

Comment: @ZyX are you sure it doesn't? Because when I try sorting `5(1)` and `5(2)` it does seem to sort the two correctly (I checked using the fact that there is reversal when I use the `-r` flag.)

And out of curiousity why was the previous version better? This version should be the same if not better than that last one?

Comment: @ffledgling Note that if you ever want a filename used in `!` and have no idea what this filename is (always the case when you are writing a script or when you share something with somebody) you have to use `:execute '!command' shellescape(@%, 1)`. List of possible characters in filename that will break `!command %` is too big, though most common one is a space (other characters depend on shell). Programmers tend not to use characters that are to be escaped, but users have no problems in naming directory `Contracts with CompanyName` or naming subtitles `[Team]Title - N (1080p).ass`.

Comment: @ffledgling I have checked with the data provided and it appeared to result in `jinah 48(2)`, `jinah 48(1)`, `qindao 48(2)` while second should go after the block that does not even end with the third. You must not sort with only two lines.

Comment: @ZyX duly noted. Escaping characters correctly can be a pain, and the spaces in other people's file names have definitely bitten me before.

Comment: @ZyX You're right I see the error, but I don't quite understand why it's creeping in.

Comment: @ffledgling Because `48(2)` and `48(1)` both have exactly the same key `48`. And you requested stable sorting.

Comment: By the way, just written a patch to replace `:execute '!command' shellescape(@%, 1)` with `:!command %:S`: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/-dkZbGixAmw. I once have requested this functionality, but nobody seems to bother.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vim built-in `:sort` command:

```
:sort! /\S\+\s*/
```

. The regex here makes sort skip the part of the line that matches this regex (in this case it is a sequence of non-whitespace characters (with at least one non-whitespace character) followed by a sequence of whitespace characters (with at least zero whitespace characters)). `!` reverses the order. By default `:sort` operates on the whole file, check `:h :range` about other options.

Comment: Use your reply tried or not, I added some notes in the original, I hope you can learn more about my needs. Thank you!

Comment: @shixin My answer is the same as @ffledgling except for the `--stable` key (`-s`). There is unfortunately no way vim `:sort` can be made stable. It is probably better to use his answer since there is sort for windows.

Comment: @shixin * Err: it will be the same if you remove `n` part. This sorts so that lines with `48(2)` are above lines with `48(1)` and they in turn are above lines with `47(2)`, but this assumes all numbers have the same width (if there is line with `5(1)` in second column it will be brought to the top by both my (after edit) and @ffledgling’s answer while it should be probably at the bottom). The edit is not going to make sort stable though.